# How to import data in .cypherl format using mgconsole to a Memgraph that runs in WSL?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a Memgraph running inside WSL (Ubuntu distribution). I have the data in .`cypherl` format. I don't possibility to connect with Memgraph Lab to this instance.

How can I import my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data import from `.cypherl` file can be done using the `mgconsole`. Open a terminal in your Ubuntu, go to a folder where your `.cypherl` file is located and write the following command:

```
mgconsole < queries.cypherl
```